# SciPy optimize over vector indeterminate

Tags: arrays, numpy, optimization, scipy

I want to define a function as follows:

```
def f(x,m):
    return np.exp(((x[i]-m).T)@((x[i]-m))
```

where the input is a known dataset array `x`, for example

```
x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

but also an unknown 2d vector `m`.

**At the moment I cannot define properly this function**, since I get the ERROR:

```
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```

The truth is I don't know what is the correct way to define m. Should it be something like

```
m = []
```

maybe? I know that unlike mathematica, **I need to tell something to Python regarding** `m` **but it is not clear to me what**.

Most importantly, I am interested in adding all components of `x` and minimizing the logarithm of `f(x,m)` to find the value of `m` for which `f(x,m)` is minimum.

Comment: What is `i` in the function `f`?

Comment: So the dataset is a numpy array `x`. Then `i` is the index if the row. For example `x[0]` corresponds to the first row of `x`, that is `x[0]=[1,2]`

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. Do you want to minimize `f` for a single row, `i` is constant, or the summation of all rows?

Comment: I would like to eventually minimize the sum indeed. But this is the second part of the question (how to implement the dataset in the function). The first part is how to obtain a function on indeterminate `m` that I can minimize over (irrespectively if the `x` is a single 2d vector or a list of 2d vectors).

Answer (score 1):

To minimize a function you can use the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize).

This might help you in understanding how to work with this function

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def f(m, x, i):
    return np.exp(((x[i]-m).T)@((x[i]-m)))


x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
i = 0

m = minimize(f, x0=(0,0), args=(x, i)).x
```

I changed the order of parameters of your function `f`. `minimize` expects the first parameter to be the "variable" parameter which in this case is `m`, `x` and `i` are kept constant during the optimization.

In the call of the `minimize` function, `x0` is the initial guess of `m` which is important to give because it tells the `minimize` function the shape of `m`. `args` is used to input the "constant" parameters.

The function returns an `OptimizeResult` where now the `x` attribute is the best estimate for `m`. However, the `OptimizeResult` contains some more useful information about the optimization.

Comment: If there is more than parameters to optimize, how do you implement? For example, if we multiply overall with a fact `a` and require `a>1` (I know this is trivial, but I can generalize to proper constraints afterwards as soon as I understand how to call them in the definition of `f`).